# Angular js I am not able to call my buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i need ur help figuring out this problem... im new to angular just started playing on ground.

Initially i have only one button on load "Add list", with add list user can able to add multiple lists with itself have a button("Add Phase") for each list, on click of Add phase it should show the content related to that phase.

Im doing this all in dynamic way.

My HTML looks like:

```
<button ng-click="list()">add list</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

My controller looks like:

```
    $scope.list =function(){
    var name1html = '<div id="ide"><button ng-click="phase()">Add Phase</button><div id="drop"></div></div>';
    var name1 = $compile(name1html)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('container')).append(name1);
    }


    $scope.phase =function(){

    var name2html = '<div>123</div>';
    var name2 = $compile(name2html)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(name2);

    }
```

Actual Output:
[On click of 2nd Add phase button it is again adding to 1st button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdSOm.png)

Expected Output:
[Im expecting something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlP7p.png)

Comment: you created two elements with id `drop`, but `document.getElementById` returns only the first one.

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov i have only one element with id drop, im trying to append that...

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov anyway could u please suggest me a better way to achieve my expected output...?

Comment: posted the answer below. Use classes instead of id attributes.

Comment: please give jdforsythe a look..... I basically wrote the same answer a bit too late: My fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/0088orkk/

Comment: @Steen Hey steen i actually cant pass anything to array, something like this as a template $scope.addPhase = function(item){

var name2html = '<div data-dir-temp></div>';
var name2 = $compile(name2html)($scope);

 item.phases.push({value:name2});
};

Comment: @Steen how to put some template in that case, i really liked ur fiddle, just to enhance i need to put a template like 2 input feilds 2 buttons etc, pls help me

Comment: sure.... I made an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not thinking about things the Angular way. You don't really need all those `$compile` and the HTML in your JS. Let Angular do the heavy lifting. Use an array of lists in your controller and iterate over it in the markup with ng-repeat. You can nest an inner ng-repeat for the phases inside each list. Something like this:

```
<button ng-click="addList()">Add list</button>
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="list in lists track by $index">
    <div>
      <button ng-click="addPhase($index)">Add Phase</button>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phase in list.phases track by $index">
          {{ phase }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.lists = [];

$scope.addList = function() {
  $scope.lists.push({ phases: [] });
};

$scope.addPhase = function($index) {
  $scope.lists[$index].phases.push('123');
};
```

And for good measure, here's a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kwh9mX)

Note: I removed the ids from the tags, because you don't need them for Angular (it keeps track of them internally) but if you really needed them you could use the `$index` to add a numerical value to them (to @DmitriyLoskutov point, id attributes are meant to be unique, whereas you were trying to add multiple elements with the same id value).

Edit:

You can put anything inside the phases. Like this:

```
<button ng-click="addList()">Add list</button>
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="list in lists track by $index">
    <div>
      <button ng-click="addPhase($index)">Add Phase</button>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phase in list.phases track by $index">
          <div data-exp-page exp-page-attribute-one="{{$index}}" exp-page-attribute-two="{{phase.name}}"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is just to show that you can include any HTML inside that phase `<li>`. If you need to pass attributes on the directive, you can do so. The uniqueness is defined by the `track by` value. This can be `$index` in the example, since there is no existing model with any unique value, or if you have an existing model with a unique property (database records, for instance) you can change `$index` to `list.uuid` or whatever.

You can also access the list from within the phase by using `$parent.$index` - if you want to remove a phase that was added, for instance, you could do the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="phase in list.phases track by $index">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="phase-name-{{$index}}" ng-model="phase.name">
    <button type="button" ng-click="removePhase($parent.$index, $index)">Remove this phase</button>
  </div>
</li>
```

And then in the controller:

```
$scope.removePhase = function($listIndex, $phaseIndex) {
  $scope.lists[$listIndex].phases.splice($phaseIndex, 1);
};
```

Comment: If you need the id on the list, for example, you can do this:

`<div ng-repeat="list in lists track by $index" id="list-{{ $index }}">`

(or if you want to start from 1, `id="list-{{ $index + 1}}"`)

Comment: The problem is that i need to put a dynamic template lets say some html block of code, not just the 123 that you are pushing into array... There mustbe some better way i guess

Comment: Where are you getting the template from? Is it truly dynamic, or is it from a static list of templates?

Comment: The example is not really doing what i was expected

Comment: that template itself will have a form with 3 input feilds, and buttons like add delete & modify, my only worry is that these should all have their own bounds. i.e, uniqueness

Comment: If you want truly dynamic content inside the phase, then you'll likely want to write a directive to do so. If you're using `$compile` in your controllers, you're probably doing it wrong. Angular is designed to handle most of these scenarios. Refer to http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/ for an example of a dynamic template directive

Comment: Angular keeps them unique with the `track by`. It handles that for you. If you edit your question to show what you really are looking for maybe I could help more.

Comment: hey im also using template and im compiling that template...  $scope.phase =function($event){

var name2html = '<div data-exp-page></div>' ; // a template from my directive
var name2 = $compile(name2html)($scope);
angular.element($event.currentTarget).next().append(name2);

}

Comment: @jdforsythe Hey could u please confirm me with the above way, or u can give me a suggestion to work in such scenario.

Comment: I edited my answer to show that you can use any HTML inside the phase, including plain HTML or your directives. You can access the properties of the phase to pass to attributes of the directive. You can access the unique identifiers to pass to scope functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.list =function() {
        // use class insead of id
        var name1html = '<div class="ide"><button ng-click="phase($event)">Add Phase</button><div class="drop"></div></div>';
        var name1 = $compile(name1html)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('container')).append(name1);
    };

    $scope.phase = function ($event) {
        var name2html = '<div>123</div>';
        var name2 = $compile(name2html)($scope);
        var drop = $event.target.parentNode.querySelector('.drop'); // we get the right div tag with class drop
        angular.element(drop).append(name2);
    };
```

Comment: Working brillaintly, u made some magic, at the same time i couldn't able to add an unique id using $index because i dont have any ng-repeat here... and do u suggest this way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$scope.list =function(){
var name1html = '<div id="ide"><button ng-click="phase($event)">Add Phase</button><div id="drop"></div></div>';
var name1 = $compile(name1html)($scope);
angular.element(document.getElementById('container')).append(name1);
}


$scope.phase =function($event){

var name2html = '<div>123</div>';
var name2 = $compile(name2html)($scope);
angular.element($event.currentTarget).next().append(name2);

}
```

and also remove your `id` as it being duplicated whenever `phase` is triggered

Comment: Hey thanks This is working fine, do u think whatever the way i choosed to perform this is actually the ryt way or will u be able to suggest any better way if i say i further put some input feilds that should actually relate to the context and im also facing a problem giving a unique id for each list and each phase...

Comment: they need not be only `id`...you could give a `class` and transverse the `dom` using jqlite fuctions as I did (note I'm not using any class or id to put content, I'm just finding the `next` sibling and `append`ing the content ) or use vanilla js as @dmitriy did...any way should be fine as long as you know how to transverse through dom and reach your elements

Comment: If you're "transversing the dom" in Angular you are doing it wrong. Angular is specifically built to transverse the DOM so you don't have to. Why even use Angular? You should not need `document.getElementById` in your controllers, ever.

Comment: well it really depends on what you want to implement.. if you think angular is really implemented to transverse the DOM, (which I don't agree at all) why would you have support for functions like jqlite?

Comment: The Angular team has stated many times that you shouldn't do DOM manipulation within controllers. JQLite is there because it's needed inside your directives where it's okay to do DOM manipulation. What the OP is asking is exactly why ng-repeat was designed, to easily repeat DOM elements without needing to access the DOM from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

using the repeats as "templates" - notice the textarea which reflects the items in the list:

http://jsfiddle.net/0088orkk/1/

The object generated by the "user created list" and entered values can be sent, stored or manipulated quite easily.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="button" value="addList" ng-click="addList()"/><br/><br/>

<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">   <input type="button" value="addPhase" ng-click="addPhase(item)"/>
          <div  ng-repeat="phase in item.phases">
          {{phase.value}}
          <form>
          <input type="text" ng-model="phase.Value1"/>
          <input type="text" ng-model="phase.Value2"/>
          <input type="text" ng-model="phase.Value3"/>
          </form>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul><br/>
    <br/>
     <hr/>
    <br/>
    Items:<br/>
<textarea style="width:400px;height:400px">{{items}}</textarea>   

</div>



function MyCtrl($scope) {


$scope.items =[];
$scope.addList = function(){
    $scope.items.push({phases:[]});
};
$scope.addPhase = function(item){


    item.phases.push({value:123});
};


}
```